# Copy Folder to another Folder using WP Filesystem

Tags: directory, wp-filesystem

I want to copy a plugin folder to another folder, outside the  WordPress installation, but in the same host, accessible via the same FTP account.

Is there a way? I read something about copying directories, but I don't understand it. How i made it and is it a `.php` file?

Maybe the following code will work?

```
global $wp_filesystem;
$wp_filesystem->copy_dir( 
    '/path/you/are/copying/from/', 
    '/path/you/are/copying/to/'
);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried the code snippet you posted? If yes: How and where? In a plugin? And what do you mean by _"How i made it and is it a `.php` file?"_ ?

Comment: Funnily enough @kaiser had a what the hack universe moment here :) You might want to read »[How do I ask a good question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)« and take a look at the [help] for more information.